# Command not found when remote run cmd with RPYC

Tags: python, rpyc

I started rpyc_classic service on slave A
Here is the PATH in A:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin/bash:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.x86_64/bin:/home/hscaleflux/.local/bin:/home/hscaleflux/bin
```

But I get wrong PATH by rpyc:

```
conn = rpyc.classic.connect(host)
os_mod = conn.modules.os
os_mod.environ.get("PATH")

>>>'/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin'
```

With this wrong path. I will get

```
"Command not found"
```

when run command not in "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin"".

Any solutions?

Comment: How you start rpyc server part? It's ok on myside.

Comment: Start rpyc remotely by ssh command.